# why does this code reverse a string what exactly does each line of code do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

fairly new to python so this string makes only half way sense to me, can someone explain to me what is going on in this code

```py
def rev(st):
    s = ""
    for ch in st:
        s = ch + s
    return s

print(rev("hello"))
```

Comment: `for ch in st:` iterates over `st` by character. So first ch is "h", and s is set to `"h" + ""` ie s = "h". Next itertaion of the for loop ch is set to "e" and then s is set to "e"+"h". Next ch is set to "l" and s is set to "l"+"eh". And so on. But please don't ask questions like this on stack overflow, you should learn python on your own. I recommend reading all the way through https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: This question is liable to downvotes as it shows that you have done little to know what `rev` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "bc"
ch = "a"
ch + s = "a" + "bc" = "abc"
```

The for loop just iterates through the string and applies this function to each ch it encounters.

Answer (score 0):

When "summing" strings, the order of variables matter.

```
'a' + 's' != 's' + 'a'
'a' + 's' = 'as'
's' + 'a' = 'sa'
```

What is that happening in the loop is that you are assigning each letter to the left side of the empty string.

```
Iteration one: ch + s = 'h' + '' -> 'h'
Iteration two: ch + s = 'e' + 'h' -> 'eh'
etc
```